# In .NET, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll, Version=8.0.0.0 requires System.Runtime.dll Version 8.0.0.0, but no such version exists

Tags: .net, dll, gac

In .NET, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll, Version=8.0.0.0  requires System.Runtime.dll Version 8.0.0.0, but no such version exists anywhere on the internet or in the GAC.

I tried binding redirects onto System.Runtime.dll Version 4.0.20.0 and 4.0.0.0, but the FUSLOGVW.exe binding error is:

LOG: Assembly Name is: System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.

Answer (score 0):

Found in C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1